# Can font-size be set to a percentage of page-width?

Tags: android, html, iphone, css, mobile

I am making a mobile site, and trying to do it so the title h1 tag will adjust to 80% of the screen size.

Comment: the browser must support this, yes support and you can use responsive method to develop your site for every screen you want

Answer (score 2):

According to [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) (Candidate Recommendation), you can use the `vh` unit, which is equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block. So for example, `font-size: 5vh` would set font size to 5% of the body width. [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) is fairly good in newest versions, but this excludes e.g. IE 8. This more or less answers the question in the title.

The description in the body of the question is something rather different. The font size is the height of the font and does not have any defined relationship with the widths of letters (which vary), so there is really no way in CSS to make some text occupy 80% of some width. You can set the width of an `h1` element of course, but this is very different from setting the width of its text content. You would need JavaScript to set the text width.

Answer (score 0):

Font size can't be use as percentage (%)
you can use em and px extensions for font size
for example
font-size:2 em;

or
font-size:10px;